# Android приложение которое бросает игральные кости рандомно

Tags: java, android

Есть шесть изображений развёртки кубика. Их имена по порядку: dice_1.png, dice_2.png и т.д.
Когда я запускаю код то на первый взгляд все нормально и видны игральные кости.
Но когда нажимаю кнопку "Бросить". То все исчезает и больше ничего не происходит.
Было бы хорошо если сможете создать массив и все изображения (dice_1.png, dice_2.png и т.д.) можно закинуть туда. Сможете помочь?
-Мой код:

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_left"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dice_2"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_right"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/dice_4"/>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_roll"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:text="Бросить"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.dice;

import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView mLeftImageView;
private ImageView mRightImageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button rollDicesButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_roll);
    mLeftImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_left);
    mRightImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_right);

    rollDicesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Получим случайные числа для двух костей
            int value1 = randomDiceValue();
            int value2 = randomDiceValue();

            // Находим ресурс с этими числами
            int res1 = getResources().getIdentifier("dice_" + value1,
                    "drawable", "ru.alexanderklimov.dice");
            int res2 = getResources().getIdentifier("dice_" + value2,
                    "drawable", "ru.alexanderklimov.dice");

            mLeftImageView.setImageResource(res1);
            mRightImageView.setImageResource(res2);
        }
    });
}

private int randomDiceValue() {
    Random random = new Random();
    return random.nextInt(6) + 1;
}
}
```

Comment: `ru.alexanderklimov.dice` замените на `com.example.dice`. И разбирайтесь в коде, который копируете с туториалов, а не просто копируйте)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может так?

```
...

// Находим ресурс с этими числами
int res1 = getResources().getIdentifier("dice_" + value1,
        "drawable", "com.example.dice");
int res2 = getResources().getIdentifier("dice_" + value2,
        "drawable", "com.example.dice");

...
```

Comment: ДАА спасибо братан будь здоров